# Seeing if values in a list are of equal value ~Python

Tags: python, list

I was wondering if their is a way to see similar values in a list. So i could say if 2 numbers of the list are of equal value print that number. Thanks for the help

EDIT:
i was wondering if this would work

```
a = []
v = 0 
while v == 1:
  n = x - (func1sub/func1dsub)
  a.append(n)
print (a)

d = defaultdict(int)
for v in a:
  d[v] += 1
print (v)
```

Comment: did you try it?  `while v == 1:` will fail since `v` is not defined...

Comment: would their be a way to somehow find if numbers where close to each other? so it would say if 2 numbers in the list are .0001 of a difference print that number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called a histogram.  After you have a histogram, printing what numbers satisfy your condition is easy.

There are a few ways to create a histogram. Lets assume we have this list defined:

```
list_ = [1,1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6]
```

**By Hand**

```
histogram = {}
for i in list_:
    oldfreq = histogram.get(i, 0) # get the old number of times we've seen i, or 0 if we haven't seen it yet
    histogram[i] = oldfreq+1  # add one to the old count
```

If you have Python >= 2.5, you can use [`defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.defaultdict) to simplify those two lines in the loop

**defaultdict**

```
from collections import defaultdict
histogram = defaultdict(int) # this means, "if we haven't seen a number before, set its default value to the result of int(), which is 0
for i in list_:
    histogram[i] += 1
```

If you have Python >= 2.7, you can use [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is specially-made for histogram creation

**Counter**

```
from collections import Counter
histogram = Counter(list_)
```

Now that you have your histogram, you can filter it to get only those numbers that occur more than once.

```
twoormore = [n for n,freq in histogram.iteritems() if freq > 1]

print twoormore
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l = [1,2,2,3]
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for v in l:
...   d[v] += 1
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 1})
>>> [v for (v,c) in d.iteritems() if c > 1]
[2]
```

So `2` is the only value that appears more than once.

Note that the time complexity of this approach is linear since it only has to traverse the list once to build the dictionary.  Calling `count` for each item in the list would be quadratic time.

Comment: Dictionary-based solutions assume that the list items are hashable, which is not a problem for numbers (as in Shantanu's question) but is important to be aware of. Also, a `collections.Counter` would be even easier.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my variant:

```
In [12]: a = [1,1,2,3,4]

In [13]: z = set([(val,a.count(val)) for val in a])

In [14]: z
Out[14]: set([(1, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1), (2, 1)])
```

Comment: sorry, i dont really see what this is doing though, i want to see what number in the list is equal to another number in the list so some function that would find that their are multiple instances of the number 1 so print 1

Comment: This creates a tuple with the value, and the number of occurences. This way you could check for all combinations where the number of occurences is greater than 1.